# Handling iOS 8's Changes To App Containers within Xamarin (alternative to Environment.GetFolderPath)

Tags: file-io, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8

Per the thread started at (http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24860/documents-directory-has-moved-in-ios-8#latest), we are working to adapt our App to the recent changes make in iOS regarding accessing the iOS 8 file structure.  We have reviewed and attempted the implementation of the code found within the iOS 8 Note at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/#Creating_Files_and_Directories, and while the results of the sample code does provide some environment 
variables, some additional instructions and how to get the results to behave in the same manner as Environment.GetFolderPath would be helpful – or guidance on whatever the appropriate approach should be.

The following takes place after a Release archive is built and pushed to an iPad device running iOS 8.0 (note not 8.0.1).  We are using the following code:

```
var documents = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls
   (NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory,
    NSSearchPathDomain.User)
   [0].Path
```

And we get:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8C4D70BC-7607-xxxx-xxxx-A503A061E1EF/Library
```

But when we try to write to files in this directory, we get the following error in the device log:

```
Sep 25 12:47:22 Cognilores-iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SEXI_reader(1243) deny file-write-create /usr/share/CogniLore
```

Is anyone able to help us identify what is going wrong and what workaround we can use?  This is a severe issue – our App crashes immediately after users upgrade to 8.0, and we need to get an updated version into the approval process as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Is anyone able to help us identify what is going wrong

The path you show does not match the path from the device logs. Are you sure they come from the same code ?

e.g. maybe another part of your application later try to access a different directory (and this is what you're seeing in the logs) ?

Some quick test shows that the code (below) works fine on iOS8 devices.

```
var urls = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls (NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User);
var path = urls [0].Path;
File.WriteAllText (Path.Combine (path, "myfile.txt"), "woohoo");
```